# Is it possible to install Ubuntu in UEFI/EFI boot mode?

Tags: uefi, system-installation

I'm going to replace my old PC, and the new motherboard wont't have a traditional BIOS but uses UEFI boot mode. Is it possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 with this setup? Are there any known problems?

I found some info about it online, but I would like to be sure before actually buying the components for my new PC.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit is supposed to be the release which supports UEFI boot... is that correct?

I only intend to run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on this computer; no dual-boot with other OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit on New PC with UEFI, and it work fine!**
In UEFI settings there is possibility to disable/enable Secure boot mode.

Comment: You should probably accept @falstaff or Rod Smith's answer. Yours was posted 5-6 days later and says basically the same thing. Your answer would be more appropriate as a comment. Just my 2 cents

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 on an EFI-based system. Yes, there are also potential problems. Secure Boot is one potential problem. Another is that some computers have broken EFI implementations that don't honor their NVRAM boot loader settings, meaning you must copy your boot loader file to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the EFI System Partition (ESP). There are an assortment of other potential minor EFI-specific problems, most of which are fairly rare.

In a worst-case scenario, you should be able to install Ubuntu in BIOS/legacy mode -- most EFI motherboards support this type of operation. This may be limiting in the future, though, particularly if you've got an over-2TiB disk and you want to install Windows to it.

Overall, I'd say: Just try it. If you run into problems, look for help in the forums or check here. (There are lots of EFI-related questions here, along with answers to most of them.)

Comment: Thankyou very much! I just have to try!
if something goes wrong, i hope someone (into forum) will help me! :)
I'll let you know!

Answer (score 2):

Yes Ubuntu 12.04 supports UEFI. However, it does not support Secure Boot, so you have to make sure Secure Boot is turned off in your BIOS configuration.

Comment: Thanks!
I've not interest about secure boot, I just wanted confirmation to install Ubuntu on my new mother board.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification. Ubuntu 12.04.02 64 bit or later support UEFI and secure boot.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI